# Angularjs - sum object value in a controller in an array

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, function, controller, sum

I am trying to get cost sum from object array in controller. I got this array from mongo collection

```
vm.costs = CostsService.query();
```

and then invoke a function to calculate cost sum

```
  vm.sum = function (items, prop) {
  console.log(items);
  return items.reduce(function (a, b) {
    return a + b[prop];
  }, 0);
};

vm.costTotal = vm.sum(vm.costs, 'costprice');
```

I don't know why I got 0 value instead of real sum of costs.
I checked the items in a console in Chrome browser, but list is showing in proper way.

[console.log() screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkkiG.png)

There is one interesting thing, if I added in controller hardcoding array and then invoke the sum function everything looks good. I think that problem is in array from mongo, but I don't have any ideas how do this to get this cost sum.

My CostService method below:

```js
// Costs service used to communicate Costs REST endpoints
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('costs')
    .factory('CostsService', CostsService);

  CostsService.$inject = ['$resource'];

  function CostsService($resource) {
    return $resource('api/costs/:costId', {
      costId: '@_id'
    }, {
      update: {
        method: 'PUT'
      }
    });
  }
}());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be because your `CostsService` might be returing a `Promise` resolving `costs` instead of `costs` array directly. To solve that, you need to call the `vm.sum` inside `.then` of your promise returning service call. Like this:

```
  vm.sum = function(items, prop) {
    console.log(items);
    return items.reduce(function(a, b) {
      return a + b[prop];
    }, 0);
  };

  CostsService.query().$promise.then(function(costs) {
    vm.costs = costs;
    vm.costTotal = vm.sum(costs, 'costprice');
  });
```

Comment: Yes you have a right it's returning Promise, but when I try do this using .then(function(costs){...}) I've got an error that .then is not a function.

Comment: @BogusławBoczkowski can you share your service code too? I think it's because of that you are getting this error

Comment: @BogusławBoczkowski check now. For `$resource`, we need to add `$promise` like I updated in the answer. Also, remove your service as answer and you can edit your question and put it there